# Kivy Python Mouse Position

Tags: python, mouseevent, kivy

I am trying to write a app where i can get the mouse position all the time. right now they code i have needs to be clicked in order to get mouse position BUT i want to get position all the time.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MousePos(App):
    def build(self):
        from kivy.core.window import Window
        self.label = Label()
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=lambda w, p: setattr(self.label, 'Mouse Position', str(p)))
        return self.label

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MousePos().run()
```

What can I add to get mouse position as I drag my mouse on the screen I get its position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually getting the position all the time. To display it, however, you need to change `text` attribute of your label:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MousePos(App):
    def build(self):
        from kivy.core.window import Window
        self.label = Label()
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=lambda w, p: setattr(self.label, 'text', str(p)))
        return self.label

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MousePos().run()
```

The code `setattr(self.label, 'Mouse Position', str(p))` actually adds a new property to label object, called `Mouse Position`, that is never used.