# How to get pressed button coordinates (gridlayout)

Tags: python, kivy

```
n = int(input())

def call_back(self):
    pass

self.layout = GridLayout(cols=n, rows=n, 
                         size_hint = (0.5625, 1), 
                         pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5})

for _ in range(n ** 2):
    b = Button(on_press=self.call_back,
               background_color=(25, 25, 25, 1))

return self.layout
```

call_back function should return pressed button coordinates, but I don't know how to implement that

Comment: You can try getting the [position of the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662672/kivy-python-mouse-position) as it clicks the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the coordinates as in row and column of the `GridLayout`, then you can just store that information in the `Button` for easy access:

```
    for row in range(n):
        for col in range(n):
            b = Button(on_press=self.call_back,
                       background_color=(25, 25, 25, 1))
            b.coords = (row, col)
            self.layout.add_widget(b)
```

Then you can access that information in the `call_back()`:

```
def call_back(self, button):
    print('call_back:', button.coords)
```